# Premium (SSD) managed disks for Azure VM Scale Set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I've been trying to get Premium managed disks (SSD) enabled for Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets, but I don't seem to get it setup.

[image: Scaleset config]

Standard (HHD) seems to work for managed disks.

Anybody got this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pick SSD capable VM's when creating the VMSS.
[image]

The VMSS portal page would say that its still using HDD, but if you check the actual resource properties it would say:

```
"storageProfile": {
    "osDisk": {
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "managedDisk": {
            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
        }
    },
    "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "offer": "WindowsServer",
        "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
        "version": "latest"
    }
},
```